# Change appearance of links with plotly/dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm working with [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) to build a dashboard. Consider the following code:

```
def get_index():
    index = html.Div([
        dcc.Link('Page 1', href='/page-1'),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Link('Page 2', href='/page-2')
    ], style = {'display':'inline-block','columnCount': 2})
    return index
```

This gives me the following output in my app:

[image]

**Question:** How do I remove the bar below the links and change the font and color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the links by adding `style` as a named argument, e.g.

```
dcc.Link('Page 1', href='/page-1', 
         style={'font-family': 'Times New Roman, Times, serif', 'font-weight': 'bold'})
```

The style argument is just regular CSS.

Adding [external CSS](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources) to your Dash app is preferable in my opinion because you can separate code logic and layout.

Comment: is it possible to add hover text to dcc.Link?

Comment: @user466130: Should be possible. Can you open a new question for that?

Comment: i found the way to add hover text to dcc.Link.
dcc.Link(html.Span('\u2318', title='all-domain'), href='/apps/overview')